# Python brackets substring not working, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring, square-bracket

I am new in python and doing some testing I found this.

```
>item="testing315testing08634567890"
>item.index("086")
17
>item[17:10]
''
>item[17:]
'08634567890'
```

I don't understand why is not working, while with other strings it works. Note that if I do this...

```
> item[4:10]
'ing315'
```

Are the numbers in the middle causing troubles? Is this a bug?. Did I missing something?
I am using Python 3.3

Comment: you could do `item[17:10:-1]` if your intention was to look at 17-10 backwards.  not sure if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end index of a list slice is a position greater than the start index, is *not* the size of the slice! so you want something like this:

```
item[17:len(item)]
```

Notice that this is exactly equivalent to the previous snippet:

```
item[17:]
```

The start and end indexes of a slice such as `alist[a:b]` should be interpreted like this: the slice starts at the item in the `a` position in `alist` and ends one element before the `b` position in `alist`. Both `a` and `b` are *indexes* in `alist`.

Answer (score 0):

When you index a string with a range like that, you have to place the lower bound first and the higher bound second, like so:

```
item[10:17]
```

Think of it as saying "I want this string from `a` to `b` (where `b` is excluded)" as in:

```
some_string[a:b]
```

If you want the string to the end (or from the beginning) you can simply omit the bound.

Here's an example:

```
my_string = "test"
my_string[:2]       ==> "te"
my_string[2:]       ==> "st"
my_string[:]        ==> "test"
my_string[1]        ==> "e"
my_string[1:3]      ==> "es"
```

Comment: Yes I know... in my example item[17:10] should give '08634567890', but it is not working

Comment: @user2088601, the second index is not a length, it specifies the second location in the string to grab from. Python expects the second index to be somewhere later in the string than the first one. If it's not, then it returns the empty string `""`. You're output is totally expected.

Answer (score 0):

The second number in your index must be larger than the first number. For example:

```
item[17:17]
item[17:10]
item[17:17-1]
```

will all return,

```
''
```

If you want to get the 10 characters after the matched index you could do something like this:

```
>item="testing315testing08634567890"
>item[item.index("086") : item.index("086")+10]
'0863456789'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the second argument is an ending index. but a nice hack works too:

```
list[x:x+len]
```

so if you want 10 chars, starting at 17 like in the example:

```
item[17:17+10] will give you the desired result.
```

note: this will not cause any index errors but if the string is shorter than the end index (17+10 == 27) it will yield the same result as item[17:]. the accepted answer solves the proposed question, but if you wanted 10 from the middle:

```
item="testing315testing08634567890some_other_stuff_here"

item[17:] == "08634567890some_other_stuff_here"
item[17:17+10] == "08634567890"
```

the 17+10 notation is kept because it clearly shows the intention and allows for easy substitution of variables which might not be known until runtime.